# Django on Linux Apache Webserver (Chrome doesn´t load)

Tags: django, linux, apache, webserver, wsgi

I am trying to install a Django Webserver on a Linux Apache2 Webserver.

I am Stuck and dont know why I am not getting any Response from the Webserver.

My Apache Conf:

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/venvs/djangoVenv
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/DjangoProject/

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/DjangoProject

        Alias /static /var/www/DjangoProject/static

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/DjangoProject/DjangoProject/wsgi.py
        WSGIProcessGroup DjangoProject
        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        <Directory /var/www/DjangoProject/DjangoProject>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/DjangoProject>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/DjangoProject/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And my Python wsgi File:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DjangoProject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have running my Django Server on Port 80 but Chrome only shows me, that the Website is unreachable.

[Chrome Reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOhyF.png)

**Edit:
I did a few changes and my apache Conf now looks like this:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/TestProject
        ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom.log combined
        Alias /static /var/www/TestProject/static
        <Directory /var/www/TestProject/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/TestProject/media
        <Directory /var/www/TestProject/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/TestProject/TestProject>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess TestProject python-path=/var/www/TestProject python-home=/var/venv/djangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
        WSGIProcessGroup TestProject
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/TestProject/TestProject/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

**Now when I try to load the Website Chrome is loading forever and dosen´t stop.
After a while this shows up:**
[Gateway Timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnAWU.png)

Comment: Please give more specific infos: are you new to setting up apache on Linux? Did you get the 'standard' Apache running? I would recommend to first get Apache running and then in a second step run setup a virtual host with wsgi / django.

Comment: I have set up a Apache Webserver with Django WSGI on my Raspberry Pi but on my V-Server it´s not working.
I got the Apache running and its showing me the default index.html

Comment: What do you mean with "my django server is running on 8080" ? The virtual host is defined on 80.

Comment: Thats correct I switch the Port to 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed this Video Step by Step and it just Works:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_kQheCnds

I don´t know what was the Problem but now it works.